# Expo select dropdown with images

Tags: react-native, select, expo

I am building my first mobile app with expo and I would like to have a select dropdown with images.
I already have this:

```
import SelectDropdown from 'react-native-select-dropdown';

export default function Test() {
    const countries = ["Germany", "Canada", "Australia", "Ireland"];
}
return (
    <View>
        <SelectDropdown data={countries} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is working fine but instead of the country names I want to use flag icons.
Does anyone has an idea how to implement this?

Comment: Check the examples in the library, they show how to do this.